# Cordova Push Plugin: onNotificationGMC is not fired and cannot obtain regID

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone I'm developing a cordova Hybrid app that requires the Push Notification Service of Android and iOS to work and so I've installed the cordova plugin "[PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)".

Here's my code

document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);

```
function deviceready() {
    try {
        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
        pushNotification.register(
            successHandler,
            errorHandler, {
                "senderID": "7645XXXXXXXX",
                "ecb": "onNotificationGCM"
            });

        function successHandler(data) {
            alert("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        };

        function errorHandler(e) {
            alert("ERROR" + e);
        }


        function onNotificationGCM(e) {
            alert("Done")
        }

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

When I run my application I expect to have two alert: the succesHandler one and the onNotificationGCM one but it only fires the succesHandler one saying: "OK"... With this problem I can't even access the regID parameter that will be stored in my server...

Can someone please explain me how to get the regID.. All my work depend on this

I'm testing this app on a Galaxy S4 Mini with Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED

I moved the onNotificationGCM in an empty script tag like this:

```
<script>
function onNotificationGCM(result) {
    alert(result.regid);
}
</script>
```

And now it give you the regID :)

Comment: I've had to attach my callback functions like `onNotificationGCM` and `onNotificationAPNS` to `window`. Seems to be a scoping issue of some sort.

Comment: I get regID, but when I submit message on it, it says "InvalidRegistration",, I checked project number (sender id) and also activated GCM APIs.. and reviewed server api key.. all okay.. but it says.. invalidRegistration Error.. any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are using AngularJS + IonicFramework you do not have to do this:

After you create your factory with your onDeviceReady function, creates onNotificationGCM function. Something like this:

app.factory('PushProcessingService', function () {
..

});

function onNotificationGCM(e) {
}

I was creating onNotificationGCM inside my factory. This solve my problem. I hope it can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In the ionic-framework you have a ready plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

here is an example for a working code for android devices:

```
module.run(function($cordovaPush) {

var androidConfig = {
    "senderID": "replace_with_sender_id",
    "ecb": "replace_with_the_name_of_function that will return you the regid"
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
$cordovaPush.register(config).then(function(result) {
  // Success
}, function(err) {
  // Error
})

window.function replace_with_ecb(notification) { //notification.regid
  switch(notification.event) {
    case 'registered':
      if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
        alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
      }
      break;

    case 'message':
      // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
      alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
      break;

    case 'error':
      alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
      break;

    default:
      alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
      break;
  }
};

}, false);
});
```

this code only works a real device(not an emulator)