# OnNotificationGCM is not called in ionic

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811170/ionic-cant-get-reg-id-for-gcm?newreg=ce2489a3a7c54247ac2f1f09706a5766) post i tried all the ways, but still not getting registration id. Kindly some one help me on this.

I am able to see the registration id in eclipse's logcat but it is not calling onNotificationGCM method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use latest push plugin. Install plugin to your project with this command:
`ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push`
To register your device use this line in your js code, this line will only register your device.

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "your-sender-id"}} );
```

Now that your device has been registered, and event with device token is generated from GCM service,which you can receive in your application using following code

```
push.on('registration', function(data) {
        // data.registrationId , use this token
});
```

That is it. You do not have to use old plugin because latest one is more simpler to use. Here is [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) to documentation of latest plugin.

Comment: Can you please tell how to install latest push plugin through command? I am using cordova 8.Is it enough if i just type ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push? or do I have to add anything in config.xml?